# Are "identify this tool/paper/technical book" questions off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, vote-to-close

Many other sites (SciFi SE, Movies and TV SE, Literature SE) allow "identification requests" where you state what you remember about a book or movie and ask for help identifying it. Are any of this kind of request (e.g. "Identify this book" / "identify this paper" / "identify this tool") on topic here, or should they all be closed as requests for off-site resources?

The reason that these seem different than "ordinary" recommendation requests is that they're not really unconstrained requests for lists of things, they're not opinion-based (there's presumably only one correct answer, and the answer is objectively correct or incorrect), and they'd be unlikely to attract spam. That being said, the "usual" rationale for closing recommendation requests simply doesn't apply.

Comment: What type of questions are you expecting - identify tool from screenshots? Book from code snippets? Paper from text snippets? All this sounds ridiculous. Help me understand your thought process please.

Comment: are there any examples of such questions in SO?

Comment: I only know of *identify this bug* questions but they come without code ...

Comment: "...these questions aren’t educational in any way, because there’s no way to learn about the process of discovery. A particular community member, by virtue of their experience in the field, just happens to be able to take the limited information you remembered and fill in enough of the blanks to guess the correct answer... guessing game questions do not meet our goal of making the Internet better." (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### They're off-topic...and likely low quality.

Finding a paper, journal, etc. is not covered by the guidelines in our help pages as it not one of...

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**

As a user over on M&TV SE where we (reluctantly) still allow "identification" questions I can assure you that they are predominantly **low quality**.

We close / delete 60% of all ID questions because of the low quality (although some argue we have exacting standards) and research shows that the askers tend not to stay and contribute to our end of the SE universe.

Anime SE, I understand, banned ID questions for the same reasons.

---

In short, these questions tend to be low quality, of little lasting value and the OPs tend not to continue to contribute.